# Platform-independent User interface library for use with GLUT

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform, glut

I am trying to write a GLUT application in C++ that requires some simple user interface. I need to be able to input text(in fact double values), click radio buttons and check boxes. The application I am bulding needs to be platform-independent so I am looking for a UI library that also is. Searching through the internet I found quite a few possibilities but I think it will take some time to discover their pros and cons. Could someone share previous experience with that sort of thing?

Some of the alternatives I have seen: [GLUI](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~rademach/glui/), [PUI](http://plib.sourceforge.net/pui/) as recommended in these [glut examples](http://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/RobTheBloke/www/opengl_programming.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [AntTweakBar](http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar) -- I've used it before because it's integrated in the c++ framework Cinder and I've found it to be quite easy to use there.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out - it seems just as what I am looking for.