# Cross platform way to create file dialog in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, filesystems, cross-platform

I am writing an application in which I need to be able to browse for an existing file and to create a new one. I need to create user interface for that. Is there any good cross-platform free library to help me do that?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366043/what-are-some-of-the-best-cross-platform-c-ui-toolkits-today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) a try, a GUI library in C++, free, open-source,... and work with the native graphics libraries.

Comment: It seems this would solve my problem, but I as I already use GLUT and AntTweakBar in my project adding dependancy to wxWidgets just for the file dialog seems a bit too much. I am searching for something not that complex if possible. +1 anyway as the answer does solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not already using a cross-platform UI library, then it doesn't make a lot of sense to introduce a dependency upon a huge library just to display a file dialog.

Since recommendations for a cross-platform UI library have already been hashed out repeatedly in other questions (use the search feature to find them if you're interested) and are probably off-topic anyway,
I'm going to take the liberty of assuming that such is not your question.

Therefore, the answer is that no, there is no reliable, cross-platform way of creating a file dialog. Each platform provides a different interface/API for this, so you'll need to write code to detect the current platform and then display the dialog as instructed by each platform's documentation.

You can do this either at run-time (if you want to have a single binary), or at compile-time by using conditional compilation (`#if` statements).

This is basically all that any UI library would be doing, and for such a simple requirement (a single feature) it makes sense to me at least to just do that work yourself.

Comment: I am in fact using GLUT + AntTweakBar As recommended here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157861/platform-independent-user-interface-library-for-use-with-glut unfortunately AntTweakBar will not help for this purpose.